# Screenshot of UIView with UIScrollView inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIView which contains an UIScrollView inside, actually it contains an UIImageScrollView, a class which helps me to zoom an UIImage, and I want to take a screenshot of UIView with zoomed UIImage, I found this function:

```
 func captureCrop() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewCapturedFoto.frame.size, true, 0.0)
    self.viewCapturedFoto.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image;
}
```

but when the screenshot is done the new UIImage is showed without zoomed image, I mean the UIImage is still not zoomed even if I zoomed it.
I don't know if I have explained it right enough

Comment: Maybe you could put screenshot of your screen and insert it here to be able to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with the size argument you are passing into your UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function. Right now you are passing in the size of the entire frame, which in scroll views, includes the off the screen portion as well. You might try changing the size argument to the bounds of the device screen or, worst case, putting your UIImageScrollView inside another view and using the bounds of this container view to set the image size.

Documentation for your reference:

**Declaration**

func UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_ size: CGSize, _ opaque: Bool, _ scale: CGFloat)

**Parameters**

size:
The size (measured in points) of the new bitmap context. This represents the size of the image returned by the UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext function. To get the size of the bitmap in pixels, you must multiply the width and height values by the value in the scale parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it returns an UIView tho

```
let screenShot = self.viewCapturedFoto.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
```

for more info visit this section of [**Apple Docs**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScreen/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:)